# Problem with my function in C when trying to find a string in a text file

Tags: c, string, file, pointers

I am trying to check the existance of a string in my text file, I already wrote a function that transforms my file content into a string.

```
char*read(FILE*f);
```

the function I wrote to find String is:

```
int find(FILE* f, char* M){
   char*chaine=read(f);

  
   if(strstr(chaine, M)!=0){
    
    printf("\n Word exists");
    return 0;
   }
   printf("\nThe word doesn't exist!!");
     return -1;
   
}
```

Example of a text file:

> Hey I am a beginner C learner.

when I try with the word **"He" it says that the word exists.**

Comment: `strstr()` checks for a string of characters, not for a **complete word**. The string `He` exists in the first part of the file: "**He**y I am a beginner C learner.". You can check if the string found is delimited by spaces or begin/end of text.

Comment: Use `strtok` to split the string when you encounter a space and `strcmp` to check if the word matches.

Comment: Your post does not actually contain a question. We can sort of infer you want to find only complete words, but you should state that explicitly, and you should think about what your goals are and how to express them. When search for “shoe”, would “shoes” match? When searching for “He”, would “he” match? State in terms that can be implemented with a computer what criteria distinguish whether something matches or does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strstr()` is finding the string `He` because those characters are found in `Hey`. You can try using `isalpha()` on the character after to see if it's the end of the word or if you've found a match within another word.

Here is an example of using `isalpha()` and `strlen()` if a match is found with `strstr()`.

```
char *example = "Hey I am a beginner C learner.";
char *ia_example = "He, I am a beginner C learner.";

char *to_find = "He";

char *match;

if ((match = strstr(example, to_find)) && !isalpha(match[strlen(to_find)])) {
    printf("\"%s\" found in example: \"%s\"\n", to_find, example);
}

if ((match = strstr(ia_example, to_find)) && !isalpha(match[strlen(to_find)])) {
    printf("\"%s\" found in ia_example: \"%s\"\n", to_find, ia_example);
}
```

Output:

```
"He" found in ia_example: "He, I am a beginner C learner."
```

`strlen()` is used to get the length of the substring you are searching for (in this case `He`) which will be length `2`. So `match[strlen(to_find)]` (ie `match[2]`) will be the character directly after the matched substring. If you put that character into `isalpha()` and it returns false, then you know the character following your substring match is not any char a-z or A-Z.

This will ensure that you're not finding a match in the middle of a word, like you did with `"Hey"`. Do note this code example doesn't take into account checking that the substring appears at the end of a word. So you would need to perform a similar check on the character before the match to see whether or not that `isalpha()`

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of using isalpha(), I read the documentation but I still don't get why we should use it. thank you

Comment: @Formerz If your issue was matching the word "Hey" when searching for "He", you can avoid that situation entirely by checking the if the character directly after the substring "He" is a letter so that you can avoid matching the word "Hey" as `isalpha('y')` will return as true. You could also perform this check on the character that is before the first character of the match to ensure you're not matching the end of a word either.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example and description of what's going on.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's more clear for me now.